Not receiving messages from Gsm sim900
I'm getting message as "Message sent" in laptop but not receiving the same message in mobile phone
Gsm module I'm using is Sim900
And the code I used is below
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

// Define RX and TX pins for SoftwareSerial
SoftwareSerial mySerial(7, 8); // RX, TX

void setup() {
  // Start hardware and software serial communication
  Serial.begin(9600);       // Serial monitor communication
  mySerial.begin(9600);     // GSM module communication

  // Give time for GSM module to initialize
  delay(1000);
  
  Serial.println("Initializing GSM Module...");
  mySerial.println("AT"); // Send AT command to check communication
  delay(1000);
  showResponse();

  // Set SMS mode to text
  mySerial.println("AT+CMGF=1"); 
  delay(1000);
  showResponse();

  // Set recipient phone number and message
  String phoneNumber = "+919663781942"; // Replace with recipient's phone number
  String message = "Hello! This is a test SMS from SIM900.";

  // Send SMS
  sendSMS(phoneNumber, message);
}

void loop() {
  // Keep listening for GSM responses
  if (mySerial.available()) {
    Serial.write(mySerial.read());
  }
}

void sendSMS(String number, String text) {
  Serial.println("Sending SMS...");
  
  // Send AT command to specify recipient
  mySerial.print("AT+CMGS=\"");
  mySerial.print(number);
  mySerial.println("\"");
  delay(1000);
  showResponse(); // Show response to confirm if number was accepted
  
  // Send the message text
  mySerial.print(text);
  delay(1000);

  // End SMS with CTRL+Z (ASCII 26)
  mySerial.write(26);
  delay(5000); // Wait for the message to send

  showResponse(); // Show response from the GSM module
  Serial.println("SMS Sent!");
}

void showResponse() {
  // Print GSM module response to the serial monitor
  while (mySerial.available()) {
    char c = mySerial.read();
    Serial.print(c);
  }
}


where are you seeing the Message sent message? ... your code does not contain the text Message sent
